# AIR ActionScript Upload Via Drop

Tags: flash, actionscript, air

I'm trying to upload a file using ActionScript, which I can do quite easily if I get the file via FileReference.browse(), what I want to do though is get the file after it has been dragged and dropped into the window.

I've got the drag and drop working fine, and I can iterate through the files like so:

```
var dropFiles:Array = e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array;
for each (var file:File in dropFiles){
    trace(file.url);
```

But how can I get these files across to FileReference.upload()? Hoping someone can help me out! Thanks!

Darren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flash.filesystem.file` extends `flash.net.FileReference`. So you can do

```
var dropFiles:Array = e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array;
for each (var file:File in dropFiles){
    file.upload(...);
```

Comment: Perfect! Always helps to have a fresh pair of eyes! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the URL, can't you just load it in with `loader.load(new URLRequest(url));`?

This post might help you if you still have trouble: http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/dragdropimageviewer/